# Bounties! At the end of each month I plan to give away a lot of my rep via bounties. Please suggest questions to receive bounties :)

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions, new-users, bounty

SE tracks our users who earn the most rep [yearly](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=year), [quarterly](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=quarter), [monthly](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month), and [weekly](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week). I often find myself at the top of all of these lists, and I figure that if I'm on the top of all of these lists, it doesn't matter if my rep earned during that period is 1 more than the 2nd place user, or 1000 more. So however much "extra" I have compared to the 2nd place user, will be donated to **other user's** questions in the form of bounties.

Since our [list of unanswered questions](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/unanswered) has now become quite large, and less manageable, I'm not sure which questions would benefit the most from a bounty, nor which users would be most deserving of having their questions featured this way.

If you have a request for your question or someone else's particular question to be offered a bounty at the end of this year, please describe your reasoning for it in an answer to this question! I'll make some simple criteria:

- (A) the question has no answers
- (B) the question is at least 6 months old (this way we know that we're tackling a question that seems like it's ***really tough*** to answer otherwise, i.e. one that is unlikely to be cleared from the unanswered queue without the offering of a bounty).
- (C) The question's edit history shows that it's been bumped in 3 separate months.
- (D) the user that asked the question must be active (check their network profile to see if they've been "seen" on MMSE in the last 30 days). If they haven't been online for awhile, they might not be interested in their question anymore, or they might have already found an answer after so long, so let's not risk "wasting" the bounty in that way. If someone other than the OP desperately wants an answer, they can add the bounty themselves.
- (E) If there's questions or comments to which the author of the question has not replied, please have those questions/comments resolved first, before we invest our bounties on such questions (I'm only allowed to offer at most three bounties simultaneously).
- (F) Priority will go to questions from users who have never had a question satisfactorily answered here yet. If a user joins this community hoping to get help, and spend time crafting a question only to find that we were not helpful, that's not a good experience. I'd like to change that by helping to get their question answered (if they've shown that they're still interested in the question, i.e. they've addressed questions/comments about their question, and they haven't disappeared).
- (G) Priority will go to questions that seem realistic to get an answer within the 7 day bounty period. Otherwise I'll add the question to [this list instead](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/109/5).
- (H) No bounties have been offered on the question in the past. I'd like to prioritize questions that haven't yet benefited from this type of "featuring", and also if a bounty has been offered in the past and didn't lead to any answers, then maybe it won't gain much from a second bounty either. More work will need to be done to get the question to attract the attention of the people that can answer it.

**Is there a question for which you'd like to request a bounty?**

Comment: At the end of the third quarter of 2023 I wanted to offer some bounties but it was too hard to decide where best to put them due to the out-of-control list of unanswered questions that have recently accumulated.

Answer (score 0):

#### My own candidate choices so far:

- <s>[How to select the projections and inner/outer window for Wannier90 calculations?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8774/5) (Asked on 9 March 2022, OP replied to follow-up in September within a day, question was bumped up on 3 September 2022).</s>  (answered by someone else, also abandoned because the last question in a comment wasn't answered)
- <s>[Cutoff length for vdW correction in DFT calculation](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/7139/5)</s>  (abandoned)
- <s>[How to plot Berry curvature flux by considering plane in momentum space?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/7149/5)</s>  (abandoned)
- <s>https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/7198/5</s> Done!
- <s>https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8585/5</s> Done!
- <s>[Applicability of GFN-FF force field and other xTB methods for dynamics of ions in water](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8623/5) (abandoned).</s>
- <s>[Cheap NMR shift calculations in periodic systems](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/8724/5)</s> (abandoned).
- https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/9260/5 (user no longer needs an answer)
- [Which researchers in electrical engineering do work related to DFT?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10666/5) (criterion C is almost fulfilled)
- [Calculation of charge transport with the non-orthogonal basis Hamiltonian based on the non-equilibrium Green's function method](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/10818/5) (criterion C is almost fulfilled)

Answer (score -1):

[Symmetrization of elastic constants based on rotational symmetry in Pymatgen](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9532/symmetrization-of-elastic-constants-based-on-rotational-symmetry-in-pymatgen)

This question satisfies all the criteria (A-G). Additionally this question was unanswered previously inspite of a bounty.

So this shows that it is a tough question.

I have figured out the answer to this question and request a bounty to be granted.

Comment: I haven't checked all of the criteria, but this question does not satisfy criterion (C): The question was bumped to the front page of the site in August 2022 and September 2022 but never again, at the time that you wrote this post. However, the author of the question has responded to your comment there, by adding a bounty, so a bounty got posted anyway :)